# JQuery to asmx fails on Windows 2008 R2 SP1

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

Since the installation of SP1 we are facing problems in calling asmx pages from JQuery client code.

IIS is pointing the JQuery post call to his default 404 page.

We did a roleback of our environment to assert this issue is caused by SP1 and tests confirm it.

Waiting for a fix @MS

**Technologies used:**

ASP.Net 4.0 - 
JQuery -
IIS 7.5 - 
Windows 2008 R2 SP1

--Bart

**Code Sample calling (front-end):**

```
  // Code to load vars...
  $.ajax({

              type: "POST",
              url: "/Handlers/ProductRating.asmx/RateProduct",
              data: "{'uniqueId':'" + uniqueId + "','productId':'" + productId + "','points':" + points.toString() + ",'showOwnScore':" + showOwnScore.toString() + "}",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              dataType: "json",
              success: function(response) {
                   alert('success');
              },
              failure: function(msg) {
                alert('something went wrong');
              }
            });
        }
```

**Code back-end:**

```
 [ScriptService]
public class ProductRating : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
    public RateProductResponse RateProduct(Guid uniqueId, Guid productId, int points, bool showOwnScore)
    {
       //Implementation
    }
```

Snapshot1 : With SP1:
http://img812.imageshack.us/i/capture2r.png/

Snapshot2 : Without SP1:
http://img190.imageshack.us/i/capture1qx.png/

Comment: So the handler is never getting called at all? Perhaps there is some default security or permission that got changed with the installation of the service pack? Seems pretty odd. The only thing that came to mind is the framework 3.5 change with adding the `d` object to JSON responses from webservices, but this doesn't seem to be your problem.

Comment: idd I confirm, handler never called ...

Comment: can you hit it directly from a web browser?

Comment: "/Handlers/ProductRating.asmx" can be hit.
"/Handlers/ProductRating.asmx/RateProduct" == 404

Comment: Sounds like an IIS config issue. I bet SP2 changes some default security setting that prohibits this. Microsoft's general approach to  security "problems" seems to be to disable things that used to be enabled by default...

Comment: We are looking in this direction but no solution found for the moment. Other people upgrading seem to have the same issue with no working fix.

Comment: FYI: issue escalated to M support

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get this working with the following addition to my web.config

I saw another site that suggested clearing the handlers, but that made everything way worse.  With this update, I was able to call my web services once again.

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="AsmxRoutingHandler" verb="*" path="*.asmx"  type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Create a Web.Config file containing the following lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.web>
            <httpHandlers>
                <clear />
                <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
                <add path="*" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler" validate="True" />
            </httpHandlers>
        </system.web>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Copy this into the directory(s) where you serve out your affected scripts, and restart your web server.

These lines will override your preferred HttpHandlers and set it to use the default handlers instead.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your screenshots, that seems an awful lot like a URL rewriting issue.  Does your site have any overly-greedy URL rewrite rules at the IIS level that could be 302 redirecting `/Handlers/ProductRating.asmx/RateProduct`?

If you do have rewrite rules, can you try disabling them temporarily to see if that fixes the ASMX issue?