# Updated to Win 2008 R2 SP1 - 404 on ajax requests with WCF

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf, http-status-code-404, windows-server-2008-r2

We are having the same issue as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456324/jquery-to-asmx-fails-on-windows-2008-r2-sp1), however we are using WCF and returning a JSON web response.

I tried changing it from .asmx to .svc but figured it would be more involved. An error results when doing this.

Is there a work-around for this issue, but when WCF is used instead of ASMX? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by deleting the handler for .svc files in IIS and readding it with exactly the same values.  See steps below for how to do this.

1. Go the main IIS node
2. Click on handler mappings in the IIS category
3. Find the node named "svc-Integrated-4.0" and delete it
4. Click on "Add Managed Handler" in the Actions bar
5. Enter the following values and click OK:

Request path: *.svc

Type: System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandlerFactory, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

Name: svc-Integrated-4.0

At this point everything should start to work.  Hope this helps.